# Is there a function in Excel to find the maximum absolute value of a range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm looking for a function in Excel that looks something like

```
= MAX(ABS(A1:A10))
```

except `ABS()` doesn't take a range of numbers.

The best that I can come up with is:

```
= MAX(ABS(MIN(A1:A10)),ABS(MAX(A1:A10)))
```

It does the trick, but it's messy as all heck and I can't believe there's not a better way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You must enter it as an array formula.  Do so by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.  The formula will appear as `{=MAX(ABS(A1:A10))}` if done correctly.

Comment: Note to numb-skulls like myself: Enter the formula then press Ctrl+Shift+Enter, I was trying to press ctrl+shift+enter first, then enter the formula, that didn't really work so well. :P

Comment: Excel is not user-friendly when it comes to matrix formulas. It behaviors is really annoying.

Comment: It is not mandatory to use an array formula (see [this](http://superuser.com/a/641624/245595) and [this](http://superuser.com/a/785751/245595). Moreover, it might be inconvenient.

Comment: This returns an error if your range also contains non-numeric data (e.g. text or formula errors)

Answer (score 27):

I don't like arrays so I would use the following:

```
=MAX(-MIN(range), MAX(range))
```

This works because the only time the absolute of the minimum number would be higher that the maximum value is if it is a negative number.

Comment: This works if your range also contains non-numeric data (e.g. text or formula errors)

Comment: Nice, this is a missing feature in excel, why not max(abs()) ??

Comment: @Julie your now +5yr old answer still has an audience. :) You propose an alternative which avoids using the array function, which you indicate you consider a plus. Do you still dislike array functions? Could you comment on why you do not (or did not) like array functions? Knowing more about your considerations might help me and other readers evaluate which solution we would like to use in which context.

Comment: This also works in OpenOffice

Answer (score 3):

Try this formula (from [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/47999-maximum-absolute-values-within-range-one-step.html))

```
=MAX(INDEX(ABS(A1:A10),0,1))
```

It combines:

- The benefits of a non-array formula, as in [this answer above](https://superuser.com/a/641624/245595) (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441885/last-non-empty-cell-in-a-column/20086410#20086410) for the benefits of non-array).
- Entering the target range only once, as in [this answer above](https://superuser.com/a/346364/245595) (less prone to errors, and easier to modify).

Answer (score 1):

This VBA solution works too.

```vb
Public Function absMax(values As Range)
    'returns the largest absolute value in a list of pos and neg numbers

    Dim myArray() As Double, i As Integer, numel As Integer
    numel = values.count
    ReDim myArray(1 To numel)
    For i = 1 To numel
        myArray(i) = Abs(values(i))
    Next i
    absMax = WorksheetFunction.Max(myArray)

End Function
```

1. Open your VBA editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>)
2. Insert a new module on the right pane
3. Copy & paste the code to the module
4. Go back to Excel and use `=absMax(A1:A3)`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

=IF(-MIN(range)>MAX(range),MIN(range),MAX(range))

This will return the **largest magnitude** number while **preserving the sign.**

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(ABS(LARGE(A1:A10,1))>ABS(SMALL(A1:A10,1)),LARGE(A1:A10,1),SMALL(A1:A10,1))
```

This will find the value with the largest absolute value out of the range but still return the actual value with its original sign (+/-) and not the absolute value.

Comment: (1) As you know, this is not an answer to _this_ question.  It is the answer to a different question.  We prefer to keep answers with the questions that they go with.  If you really want to post this answer, you might want to “ask” the corresponding question and then answer it.  ([You are allowed to do that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/271976 "Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?"), but, since you have a low [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you might have to wait several hours before you can answer your own question.)

Comment: (2) The OP already has a working answer to the question, and rejects it because “it’s messy as all heck and I can’t believe there’s not a better way.”  So why post an answer that’s twice as long as the one he already has?  For that matter, why not say just `=IF(ABS(MAX(A1:A10))>ABS(MIN(A1:A10)),MAX(A1:A10),MIN(A1:A10))`?

Comment: @G-Man This is the only formula solution, posted so far, that keeps the original sign intact, which is not explicitly requested by the OP but was helpful to me.  I respectfully disagree with both your assessments.

Answer (score 0):

=MAX(MAX(X1:X5),ABS(MIN(X1:X5)))

Comment: so how is it different from Julie's answer?

Comment: This is an answer to the question (belated, yes). Similar to Julie's, yes, slightly less efficient, perhaps, but IMHO a bit more obvious for someone who inherits the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

As of Office 365, the version posted by the OP works.

= MAX(ABS(A1:A10))

You do NOT have to use array mode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I needed to find the max and min deviation from zero, irrespective of the sign.  However, I found no way to do that using standard Excel functions when both positive and negative numbers are involved.  So, I created my own VBA functions (based on code I found elsewhere) that works every time, even when some of the values are null or strings (non-numeric).

Here are the two functions *MAX_ABS(range)* and *MIN_ABS(range, [optional boolean] allowZeros)*

*MAX_ABS* is simple and straightforward:

```
Function MAX_ABS(SelectRng As Range) As Double
    Dim result As Double
    Dim work As Double
    result = 0
    
    myarray = SelectRng.Value
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(myarray, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(myarray, 2)
            If IsNumeric(myarray(i, j)) = True Then     'Numbers Only
                work = VBA.Abs(myarray(i, j))
                If work > VBA.Abs(result) Then          'Test
                    result = myarray(i, j)              'Save new max
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
    
    MAX_ABS = result
    
End Function
```

*MIN_ABS* is a bit trickier because if you initialize the return value to zero then it will always return zero, so you need to work around that.  So I use an optional boolean parameter to allow zeros or ignore them.

```
Function MIN_ABS(SelectRng As Range, Optional allowZeros As Boolean = False) As Double
    Dim work As Double
    Dim result As Double
    Dim firstHit As Boolean
    result = 0
    firstHit = True
    
    myarray = SelectRng.Value
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(myarray, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(myarray, 2)
        
             If IsNumeric(myarray(i, j)) = True Then                'Numbers Only
                work = VBA.Abs(myarray(i, j))
                
                'Zeros allowed
                If allowZeros = True Then
                    If firstHit = True Then                         'First pass -- Initialize
                        firstHit = False
                        result = myarray(i, j)                      'Save first value
                        
                    ElseIf work < VBA.Abs(result) Then              'Subsequent pass -- Test
                        result = myarray(i, j)                      'Save new min
                    End If
                    If work = 0 Then
                        GoTo getout                                 'Zero -- no reason for further tests
                    End If
                    
                'Zeros not allowed
                ElseIf result = 0 And work > 0 Then                 'First pass -- Initialize
                    result = myarray(i, j)
                ElseIf work > 0 And work < VBA.Abs(result) Then     'Subsequent pass -- Test
                    result = myarray(i, j)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
    
getout:
    
    MIN_ABS = result

End Function
```

Here are the results of the functions on a list of values that includes numbers, strings, and blanks.

[Results of *MAX_ABS* and *MIN_ABS*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwzEW.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

```
=IF(MAX(A1:A10)+MIN(A1:A10)>0, MAX(A1:A10), MIN(A1:A10))
```

Comment: We prefer answers that include an explanation.