# Highlight max absolute value in a row of data

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to use conditional formatting to highlight the max absolute value within a row of data. For example, if my data is `10, -11, 5, -2`, I want `-11` to be highlighted to signify the largest movement from zero. Any idea how to accomplish this?

I have tried using `=MAX(ABS(range))` and modifying it to highlight the desired number, no luck yet. I have also tried using Ctrl+Shift+Enter to make it an array within conditional formatting, but no luck there either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Conditional formatting does not like CSE array formulas.

Also you need the formula to resolve to TRUE/FALSE and not return a number.

Use a formula like this:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,ABS($A$1:$A$4),1)=ABS($A1)
```

Comment: What is CSE? Ctrl-Shift-Enter?

Comment: @cat yes CSE = **C**trl-**S**hift-**E**nter

Comment: consider [that](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/97783) suggested edit then :)

Comment: @cat `CSE` is an accepted acronym, please do not edit to add the whole thing.

Comment: I've never seen it before.

Comment: @Pysis - FWIW, I've not seen it a lot on SO, but have on SuperUser. It's even used on the [Microsoft page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) about array formulas, oddly enough.

Comment: @BruceWayne I wouldn't called an "accepted acronym", but a suggested acronym, it is only suggested in the header of linked page, and then used Ctrl+Shift+Enter everywhere else in the page (39 times to be exact) vs CSE (1 time)

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate the maximum absolute value without an array formula. For data in A1:A10,

```
=ABS(A1)=MAX(-MIN($A$1:$A$10),MAX($A$1:$A$10))
```

The maximum absolute value will be the larger of the minimum value times -1 or the maximum value.

Credit to Julie for the idea in this old answer: https://superuser.com/a/641624/76571